# How do I sum the numbers of a string vertically?

Tags: python, string, methods, str-replace, strsplit

I'm trying to add all the numbers in a string in the Python language. For example,

```
s="""11 9 5
     6 6 8
     4 6 4"""
```

If we considered this string in 3 lines, and each line separated with "Enter" and some space between them, how could we this output: 21,21,17
(11+6+4 = 21) or (9+6+6=21) or(5+8+4=17). Can you help me complete it?

Comment: How is 11+9+5 = 21? Similarly for other lines. Is this a typo?

Comment: @SMA I'm guessing OP wants to add vertically, `11+6+4`, `9+6+6`, `5+8+4`.

Comment: [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) might be handy

Comment: you can use somthing like this: `list(map(sum, zip(*[map(int, i.strip().split()) for i in s.split("\n")])))
`

Comment: I mean these (11+6+4 = 21) or (9+6+6=21) or(5+8+4=17)

Comment: Will there be cases of unequal length, such as `1 2 3\n 2 3\n 3 4 5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) for vertically operations like that. and [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) for evaluating [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function to all the elements in your list:

```
s="""11 9 5
 6 6 8
 4 6 4""" 
print(list(map(sum, zip(*[map(int, i.strip().split()) for i in s.split("\n")]))))


# [21, 21, 17]
```

**Explanation**: to be honest one-linear codes are always hard to read and not maintainable :) let's break the code to these parts for better understanding:

```
list_with_string_numbers = [i.strip().split() for i in s.split("\n")]
# returns => [['11', '9', '5'], ['6', '6', '8'], ['4', '6', '4']]


map_all_str_elements_to_int = [map(int, i.strip().split()) for i in s.split("\n")]
# returns => [<map object at 0x7f991725f6a0>, <map object at 0x7f991725f730>, <map object at 0x7f9917b293a0>]

join_vertically = list(zip(*[map(int, i.strip().split()) for i in s.split("\n")]))
# returns [(11, 6, 4), (9, 6, 6), (5, 8, 4)]
```

and finally sum do the aggregation to all tuples in the list.

```
list(map(sum, zip(*[map(int, i.strip().split()) for i in s.split("\n")])))
# [21, 21, 17]
```

Comment: Thanks, It is completely true, but a little confusing!

Comment: @SeyedAmirVahabi I add Explanation to my answer. I hope this helps. you can also search about `map` and `zip` and `list comprehension` on google :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a one-line, but it is readable

```
v = list(map(int, s.split()))
# col_size = int(len(v)**0.5)
col_size = len(s.split("\n")[0].split())

res = [0]*col_size
for i in range(0, len(v)):
    res[i%col_size] += v[i]
```

Comment: `len(v) ** 0.5` ?! this does not make sense at all. what about inputs that row and column size are not equal ?

Comment: @MojtabaKamyabi You're right, I fixed it

Comment: @MojtabaKamyabi  Each line include 3 numbers and completely equal

Comment: @SeyedAmirVahabi yes. but what if your input size will change? this is not a good idea to use square root in this case

Comment: @MojtabaKamyabi Yes! It is true. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that there may be cases of unequal lengths, such as this.

```
"""
1 2 3
2 3
3 4 5
"""
```

So, based on `@Mojtaba Kamyabi`'s answer, I made a modification, replacing the function `zip` with `itertools.zip_longest`.

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables. If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in with fillvalue. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is exhausted.

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

s="""1 2 3
 2 3
 3 4 5"""
print(list(map(sum, zip_longest(*[map(int, i.strip().split()) for i in s.split("\n")], fillvalue=0))))

# [6, 9, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an one-line method:

```py
s = """11 9 5 6 6 8 4 6 4"""
out = ','.join(map(str, map(sum, zip(*zip(*[iter(map(int, s.split()))]*3)))))
print(out) # 21,21,17
```

Comment: When I open this question, `s` wasn't multiline. o(╥﹏╥)o